# Pandas return true if match on multiple column search?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to search over multiple columns and right now I'm getting the result but I really just need a true/false if there is a match.  Is there a way to do this?

Here's a sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 5)*10, columns=list('ABCDE')).astype(int)
df

    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   9   2   9   2
1   5   2   1   6   2
2   8   6   9   8   5
3   0   6   8   5   5
4   1   2   4   8   4
... ... ... ... ... ...
9995    9   3   4   9   0
9996    2   4   1   3   7
9997    4   5   2   4   9
9998    7   5   0   3   2
9999    3   5   0   5   7
10000 rows × 5 columns

df[((df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] == 1))]

A   B   C   D   E
5   0   1   7   0   6
105 0   1   2   5   9
375 0   1   0   0   3
688 0   1   8   0   9
770 0   1   7   9   5
... ... ... ... ... ...
9706    0   1   1   7   4
9710    0   1   4   4   9
9789    0   1   3   4   3
9810    0   1   1   1   5
9987    0   1   2   3   3
89 rows × 5 columns
```

Instead of getting the rows the data match, can I get true or false if the result exists in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] == 1)` is equivalent to the shorter: `df[['A','B']].eq([0,1]).all(1)`.

And your question *can I get true or false if the result exists* is equivalent to check for the series for any `True`. So are you looking for either:

```
((df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] == 1)).any()
```

or:

```
df[['A','B']].eq([0,1]).all(1).any()
```

Comment: wow! Thank you for the super fast response(are you human ?) and thanks for the clear explanation to teach me. This is helpful and works.